# how to add new business component in Siebel web tool

Tags: siebel

I have a Seibel web tools deployment in my network and am trying to add new business components and business services. However, when I click on the business components tab on the left, I do see a plus (addition) sign on the right  - above a list of existing business components. But nothing happens when I click on this plus sign.

I even looked up google and Siebel bookshelf,but could not find anything relevant. I came across some useful videos, but they just talk about how to update existing business components.

Please let me know if you have any useful articles on how to do this.

thx - Om

Answer (score 0):

That is the correct way to do it, but there a few things you need to check:

- Is the "+" button greyed out?
- Are you making the changes in the context of a DEV workspace?
- Does the browser console display any errors?
- Can you instead make a copy of an existing one and change it? In my experience it is rare to create a BC from scratch.